# Find the ratio and interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!x^n}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I believe this would diverge for $x\neq 0$. After using the ratio test I obtain (x)(n+1)(sum from 1 to n of (2n-1)/(2n+1)). Taking the limit as n goes to infinity the second term blows up and the third one would go to 1. Can someone please confirm that this is in fact correct?

Comment: In case you ever get tired of writing out $$1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n-1)$$ you can write equivalently $$(2n-1)!!$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  The ratio of successive terms is
$$\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)(2n+1)}\bigg/
  \frac{n!x^n}{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}
  =\frac{n+1}{2n+1}x\ .$$

Comment: Why is the denominator of your top term (1)(3)(5)...(2n-1)(2n+1) rather than (3)(5)(7)...(2n+1)?

Comment: Because your formula clearly shows that the terms in the denominator are odd numbers up to $2n-1$, or in this case, $2(n+1)-1$.  If it is still not clear, I suggest you write out the denominator in full for $n=2,3,4,5,6$.

Comment: Ah I see, it is merely the previous term in the sequence.

Comment: So would it converge on the interval (-2,2)?

Comment: Yes, and possibly for $x=2$ or $x=-2$ also, you would have to check those by different methods as the ratio test won't work.